# Open window modal Bootstrap with javascript without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, bootstrap-modal

I would like open a Bootstrap 3.3.7(I don't use v4) window modal. I use Google map API and I want, when I click on my Markers, don't open infoWindo of API, but open window modal. can you help me ?
I found answer with jQuery but not in javascript  without jquery. thanks for your help. sorry for my bad english

How in this envent call my window modal with id='myModal' ?

```
 myMarker.addListener('click', function () {
            //infowindow.open(map, myMarker);
        });
```

html

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Titlee</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">



                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" Value='Valider '>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just convert the jQuery answer to vanilla js?

Comment: @Cory hi thanks for your answer. Because in my project I will use only javascript, in pure javascript, no framework no libraries etc

Comment: Yes but jQuery resolves down to pure javascript.. It's just a javascript library so everything that it does can be converted to pure javascript (i.e vanilla js) If you post the jQuery solution I'm sure you'll find your answer much quicker.

Comment: @Prokzy Hi thanks for your answer. I will try, but i'm not sure of that but why not !?

Comment: see if this does anything. `document.getElementById('#myModal').classList.add('show')`

Comment: Also, you are using bootstrap, which would not be vanilla js.  I recommend using jQuery.

Comment: No nothing with : document.getElementById('myModal').classList.add('show');